# Did I correctly edit this question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I submitted a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6622019) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819115/how-to-close-a-console-application-by-typing-exit/3819137#3819137), and at the moment it has two rejections (and I have a feeling that that there will be another rejection):

[image]

I made the edit as the question's programming language is [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), but however the answer is in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23). Both programming languages use similar syntax and the code can easily be converted into VB.NET (and vice versa).

The reason for both rejections is as follows:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

I don't think that the edit deviates from the original answer, and doesn't make any changes at all to the logic of the code and preserve's the goals of the answerer.

A couple of days ago I made a [similar edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6596761) to a question that was in the same situation (converted code from C# to VB.NET) and that edit was accepted, so I must've done *something* right here:

[image]

In my opinion my edit is justified as an answer in a different programming language isn't exactly helpful for future readers, especially those new to VB.NET.
*It's a bit like posting a [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) question and getting an answer in [lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lua).*

The edit hasn't been outright rejected (yet), but am I missing something here? Are edits such as these allowed?
If not, why not?

Comment: Borderline case IMHO - I would rather first ask the answerer in the comments to convert their code.

Comment: @BartoszKP The answer was posted five years ago, and the answerer hasn't been seen for a few months. Not very likely they would respond to my comment (in good time).

Comment: You can't know until you try. Many times I've asked a poster that was last seen even a year ago, and it happened few times that after few months they replied. Sometimes they did not indeed, and only then I proceeded with my edits.

Comment: You get an email saying you've got mail from SE too.

Comment: @TankorSmash Completely depends on your mail settings on Stack Exchange, I never get any mail from SE myself.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think your edit was perfectly fine, for the reason you state you made it. It has since been approved, and only one of the users who approved it have been on Meta recently. In my opinion, the first two rejection users are wrong.

I guess I can see why they might (mistakenly) believe your edit was inappropriate. Changing the language of an answer/question definitely can be a red flag. I would have looked more closely in such a situation, perhaps - especially since you explained it in your edit reason.

In short: That's why the system works like it does - requiring three votes. Yes; it could have gone the 'wrong' way, but it worked out OK. And otherwise; don't worry about occasional rejects for that kind of thing, too. But kudos for asking about it!

Comment: The case here is simple, however, I think it would be very risky to change the programming language of the answer. Though you think it might be "very easy to convert" , it could be error-prone (unless you are familiar with both languages AND have the syntax checked) and may ruin an otherwise an acceptable answer. Not to mention the subtle difference different languages may have

Comment: Absolutely correct, @HoàngLong; changing the language would usually be Really Risky™, for those reasons.

Comment: It follows that any reviewer who's not familiar enough with *both* languages to *know* that the edit is correct should skip such a review item.

Comment: @airthomas exactly what that option is for, yes!

Comment: I'm skipping them in a hope the post owners decide what to do with the proposal. I don't know how the queue is implemented but I think it might be good if the system would check if the post owner was online say in the past 24 hours and if so, do not put the suggested edit into the queue but *wait* for the owner to make the accept/decline first by themselves.

Comment: Wow. The two who rejected have 895 edit reviews between them, and two rejections between them (ie for both this was the first time they rejected an edit). Perhaps it looked like a trap to them...

Comment: @BillWoodger Those numbers aren't right. Try reloading the page and you'll get different numbers. Those numbers are always seemingly random...

Comment: @AlexK Thanks. I get the same numbers after reloading, but looking at the Activity of the users I can see that the totals are wrong. I'm pretty sure they used to work, but I abandoned edit reviewing about a year ago, so haven't looked at them in a while :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger Perhaps those two thought it was an audit and rejected, they seem like robo-reviewers to me: http://puu.sh/e6jpX/f2232ea502.png. Perhaps some moderator should review their recent decisions to reject/accept edits to review whether they're reviewing properly.

Comment: @cybermonkey yes, that's what I thought, but look at AlexK's comment. I then checked the Activity from one of their profiles, and very quickly the count of 1 Reject turns out to be rubbish :-)